# Print value in more than one const statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Related script:

```
window.onload = function calcPreco() {
for(const cloud of Array.from(document.getElementsByName("cloud"))) {
    fetch("_config/buscar_valor.php?id="+cloud.getAttribute("cloudid")+"&periodicidade=monthly")
     .then(res => res.text())
     .then(preco => {
        preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
        const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
     })
    }
}
```

I need it to print to another `<span>` with another class, but before doing the subtraction.

I tried something like that, but it did not work:

```
.then(preco => {
        const valor = cloud.querySelector(".NEW_CLASS").innerText = preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
        preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
        const valor = cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
     })
```

That is, it must first print the original value, and then the value with the subtraction done.

How to use two const statements in this case?

Comment: ?? Nothing refers to that constant (`valor`).  It does not make sense however to declare the same variable (or constant) twice.

Comment: Looking at your code you don't need a `const` declaration at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using var or const think of it as assigning memory locations. When you assign 2 memory locations in the same scope it won't know what to do. So use different names or remove var/const from the variable declaration.
A good practice is to define and then use:

```
var someVariable;
if(condition){
   someVariable = 'some answer';
}
else
{
   someVariable = "some other answer';
}
```

Or concatenate:

```
var someVariable;
someVariable = "some"; // mostly this and the line above will be one line.
someVariable += " answer";
```

Also if you do:

```
valor = "some html";
valor = "some other html"; // This will overwrite the first answer.
```

Also a good read:

https://airbrake.io/blog/javascript-error-handling/redeclaration-formal-parameter-x

Probably what you are looking for:

```
var valor = cloud.querySelector(".NEW_CLASS").innerText = preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
preco -= cloud.getAttribute("desconto");
valor += cloud.querySelector(".mostrar_valor").innerText = preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',');
```

Comment: @3iASD...His tip almost worked, there was a problem with the score. In the first variable soon in: `preco.toFixed(2).replace('.', ',')`. If I keep this punctuation with a comma it does not do the calculation and also does not print the values. What can be done in this case?

Comment: Isn't that to convert between different currencies. The problem with the "," is that it becomes a text value. One solution is to have attribute like data-preco that is the numeric value that doesn't have the "," conversion. You can do math against that value and then have the .innerText be the visual that has the "," conversion in it.

Comment: I was able to fix just by removing `toFixed(2)`, would I have any problems with that?

Comment: Possibly. I ran this in JavaScript and this is what I got. 1.20 + 2.23 = 3.4299999999999997

Comment: A way to get around toFixed(2) is to do this: Math.floor(preco * 100) / 100;